# Select feature by id in QGIS using Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I have a ComboBox shows feature ids of selected features in a layer. I am trying to select one feature using ids in ComboBox currentIndex. I used **setSelectedFeature()**, but it didn't worked.I can't figure out how to get it.

Here is my code:

```
layer = iface.activeaLayer()
feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feat in feats:
    name = feat["id"]
    self.dlg.cb_Feature.addItem(name, feat.id())
    onefeat = self.dlg.cb_Feature.itemData(self.dlg.cb_Feature.currentIndex())
    layer.setSelectedFeatures(onefeat)
```

Comment: Can you clarify more what you are trying to do?  You have a set of selected features from which your populating a combo box by the selected feature id, then you want to only select the feature from the current value selected in the combo box?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: From API docs, it's better to use `selectByIds()` method instead of `setSelectedFeatures()`. These methods expects a list of feature to select so you need to put your feature in a list even if you just have one feature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your trying to do too much in the one loop.  Try splitting out the logic like this:

First within the plugin `run()` function make the function call to the function for populating the combobox based on feature selection.  This will populate the combo box each time the form is opened based on features selected in the map.  Then, in the `initGui()` function here is where you need the event listener for the index change on the combo box which then calls the `selectFeatures()` function, see code snippet below.

```
def selectFeatures(self):
    # continue with feature selection logic

def populateCombo(self):
    self.dlg.cb_Feature.clear()
    selectedFeatureID = []
    layer = iface.activeaLayer()
    feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
    for feat in feats:
        name = feat["id"]
        selectedFeatureID.append(name)
    self.dlg.cb_Feature.addItems(selectedFeatureID)

def initGui(self):
    self.dlg.cb_Feature.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectFeatures)

def run(self):
    self.populateCombo()
```

To get the combo box current text see:

[How do you get the current text contents of a QComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061893/how-do-you-get-the-current-text-contents-of-a-qcombobox)

To select feature based on attribute see:

[How to select features in QGIS using python](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/how-to-select-features-in-qgis-using-python/)

Comment: getting error like 'TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
     QComboBox.addItem(QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list''

Comment: Updated answer, it needed changed to addItems()

Comment: got it, but how can i select the particular feature with combobox current value(id)

Comment: Updated answer with some additional q/a links.

Comment: still getting the same issue

Comment: What do you mean by "still getting the same issue"?  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: as i mentioned above in the first comment the same one troubling me again

Comment: Did you change it to .addItems() method and are you feeding it a list object?

Comment: Yes i did .............

Comment: What is the new error message (it should be different because you updated the method to .addItems())?

Comment: This is the new error **TypeError: QComboBox.addItems(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'**

Comment: This error suggests the selectedFeatureID list has a list within it, example selectedFeatureID = ['apple', ['grape', 'orange']].  List data types may have lists within lists but not when using the .addItems() method for populating a combobox.